# How to create a Microsoft Outlook Web Add-in (Javascript) Without User Input?

Tags: javascript, outlook

I want to create an add in for Microsoft outlook that will execute its code on every new email that is received. I have followed a few tutorials and all show how to create a button to initiate an action then execute a javascript file. I'm wondering if I can create an add in that will execute on each new email received without needing the user to click a button.

P.S. I have seen you can create add ins using VSTO so is this my only option for running code in the background without user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web add-ins are run in the context of a particular item which should be opened or selected in the explorer window. You can't get them working automatically for every incoming item.

To get that working you need to develop a COM add-in (for example, a VSTO based add-in) where you should handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class. The event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getitemfromid-method-outlook) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

When using JS, you can use webhooks to get an HTTP notification when events like new e-mails occur.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks